# How to change the value of a variable in python ,using pdb debugger, during debugging mode?

Tags: python, debugging

I was using pdb dedubber in python to debug a program. The value of a particular variable was becoming zero during division due to which the program was not working currectly. I wanted to change the value of that variable during the debugging session. But I don't know how to do that?

I tried to google the same question but didn't  get any appropriate answer for the pdb debugger.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is named 'x1', then the command is:
x1=123 (or whatever)
when you are at PDB prompt.
If the name of your variable looks like a PDB command, you need to force disambiguation with:
!bt=123
But it may be easier to insert some code in your program to validate the divisor and if invalid, execute a breakpoint() instruction.